# window is not loading immediately after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html

When I click an anchor link, the current page should be loaded again immediately:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="BackToFirst"  
 onclick="popNav('BackToFirst');">Back</a>

function popNav(type) {
    if(type == "BackToFirst") {
       $(".first").show();
       $(".second").hide();
       $('.BackToFirst').click(function() {
           document.location.href =  window.location.href;
       });
    }
}
```

I expect that when a user clicks on the link, the current page will load immediately but it is taking some time to load.

Comment: How would this work? If you reload the page you need to save the state of .first and .second - please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56220698/edit) and then `[<>]` and create a [mcve] and explain the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your Click handler is only assigning a new click handler to the link, try this which just directly navigates:

```
 function popNav(type){
    if(type=="BackToFirst")
     {
        $(".first").show();
        $(".second").hide();
        document.location.href =  window.location.href;
     }
  }
```

I think that you got two concepts mixed up, the above code attaches a DOM event to the link directly on it, the other way would be to use JQuery to attach an event to that button like so:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="BackToFirst">Back</a>
```

Script:

```
   $('.BackToFirst').click(function(){
       $(".first").show();
       $(".second").hide();
       document.location.href =  window.location.href;
   });
```

If you still want to check the type then data attributes are a nice way to go when working with JQuery:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="BackToFirst" data-linktype="BackToFirst">Back</a>

   $('.BackToFirst').click(function(){
       if($(this).data('linktype') == 'BackToFirst'){
            $(".first").show();
            $(".second").hide();
            document.location.href =  window.location.href;
       }
   });
```

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't question his intent on animation, I simply helped provide him a working solution to his current code. I know that document.location and window.location is read-only but not that it isn't recommended in any useful source e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location
Fixed the missing brackets

Comment: I sincerely doubt that. "Give a man a fish...." Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Fair enough, good reads but this person is having trouble with the concept of click handlers and now you throw session storage, event bubbling, timeouts, anonymous functions, and ternary statements in. Mine just tell him how to fix his click handler, an alternative and a way to pass data if he uses the alternative

Comment: Sure. I like to be thorough ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating your code. You are binding onClick after you click on the element. I think something like this should be better.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="BackToFirst" onclick="onClickHandler('BackToFirst')">Back</a>
```

JS:

```
function onClickHandler(type){
    if(type !== 'BackToFirst') {
        return;
    }
    $(".first").show();
    $(".second").hide();
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: `something like this should be better` doesn't mean I did run it. I just forgot to pass the classname. No need to be a Z.

Comment: ? I just point out there is an issue that would confuse a noob

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to do.

1. show/hide is immediately undone when you reload the page
2. it is recommended to use location.reload(1) instead of setting the supposedly read-only document.location
3. you might want to use e.preventDefault instead of the javascript void
4. Are you absolutely sure this is not an X/Y problem? Can you explain the actual usecase?

```js
var current = sessionStorage.getItem("which"); // does not run in a snippet
current = current ? current.split("|") : []
if (current.length) {
  $("." + current[0]).show();
  $("." + current[1]).hide();
}
$(".BackToFirst").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".first").show();
  $(".second").hide();
  sessionStorage.setItem("which", "first|second")
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload(1); // are you absolutely sure this is not an X/Y problem?
  }, 500); //let the show/hide sink in  
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="BackToFirst">Back</a>
```